# Problema al dockerizar

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, docker

Estoy queriendo dockerizar mi app de NodeJs con Mysql y obtengo los siguientes errores

```
2023-09-18 15:01:56 ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:3306
2023-09-18 15:01:56     at ConnectionManager.connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:92:17)
2023-09-18 15:01:56     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
2023-09-18 15:01:56     at async ConnectionManager._connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:222:24)
2023-09-18 15:01:56     at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32
2023-09-18 15:01:56     at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:197:7)
2023-09-18 15:01:56     at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:305:26
2023-09-18 15:01:56     at async Sequelize.authenticate (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:457:5)
2023-09-18 15:01:56     at async main (/app/app.js:41:5) {
2023-09-18 15:01:56   parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:3306
2023-09-18 15:01:56       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
2023-09-18 15:01:56     errno: -111,
2023-09-18 15:01:56     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2023-09-18 15:01:56     syscall: 'connect',
2023-09-18 15:01:56     address: '172.20.0.2',
2023-09-18 15:01:56     port: 3306,
2023-09-18 15:01:56     fatal: true
2023-09-18 15:01:56   },
2023-09-18 15:01:56   original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:3306
2023-09-18 15:01:56       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
2023-09-18 15:01:56     errno: -111,
2023-09-18 15:01:56     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2023-09-18 15:01:56     syscall: 'connect',
2023-09-18 15:01:56     address: '172.20.0.2',
2023-09-18 15:01:56     port: 3306,
2023-09-18 15:01:56     fatal: true
2023-09-18 15:01:56   }
2023-09-18 15:01:56 }
```

Este es mi archivo docker-composer.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: arkhamcf
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=arkhamcf
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: [ "npm", "start" ]

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

Y este es mi archivo .env

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin
MYSQL_DATABASE=arkhamcf
MYSQL_PORT=3307
MYSQL_HOST=db
```

Y este mi archivo de configuracion de db

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
require("dotenv").config();

const db = new Sequelize(
  process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
    dialect: "mysql",
    define: {
      timestamps: true,
    },
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000,
    },
    operatorAlias: false,
  }
);

module.exports = db;
```

No entiendo porque no estaria levantando la base de datos

Comment: ¿Está corriendo MySQL en ese puerto? ¿Es realmente correcto el usuario y la contraseña? ¿3306 o 3307?

Comment: Ya probe con modificar ambos puertos y no me lo toma, probre en 3307 por si era un tema que se pizara con otro

Comment: No deberia tomar la direccion localhost para conectar?? (127.0.0.1)
Porque esta tomando otra
ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.25.0.2:3306

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de como te conectas desde node? en el docker esa direccion no existe... quizas el error está en otro lado en el código